# App sends Integers to MySQL server but refuses to send Strings

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio

I am making an app which is supposed to send a username and how many coins he has to a MySQL server, however when the app runs it doesn't submit data to the server, i tried to change the vars that are sent to an Int and another Int instead of a String and a Int and it worked, so the app only submits data successfully to the server when the vars are Int, any idea what i am doing wrong?
My code:

```
public void pushToServer(){
    String url = "http://192.168.1.103/push.php";

    StringRequest sq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            protected Map<String, String > getParams(){
                Map<String, String> parr = new HashMap<String, String>();


                int my = myBalance;
                String me = "Matthews";
                parr.put("username", String.valueOf(me));
                parr.put("coin", String.valueOf(my));

                return parr;

            }

        };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(sq);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pushed to server!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

AppController.java:

```
public class AppController extends Application {

public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
}
```

My PHP file:

```
<?php

//open connection to mysql db
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","app")
or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

// recieved from app
$username = $_POST['username'];
$coin = $_POST['coin'];

echo "Response: ".$username." ";

$sql_query = "INSERT INTO users (username,coin) VALUES 
('$username','$coin')";

if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql_query)) {
echo "Posted to server";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql_query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

As i said changing the String username to an Int works but it never works if it's a String, i am completely lost. Any thoughts?

Comment: the type of columns for username and coins are VARCHAR

Comment: Where exactly does it fail? What do you see in your logs/traces? What do you see when it works? If you don't find the exact point where it fails, add more logs. You should find where the error is (java code, php code, SQL query) and then find the exact line

Comment: The code fails at the Java side, the data is never submitted out of the app

Comment: can you post the log trace with error?